# ScrollView height doesn't fit to its content - Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView and I want to add 2 images on it. 
I created a ScrollView and then a LinearLayout. Then created 2 ImageViews and added them on LinearLayout. Then added LinearLayout on ScrollView. (All of steps by java code. Didn't use XML at all) 
But the problem is the ScrollView height is not fitted to height of my images(It's too long). 
This is my code:

```
LinearLayout scrollParent = new LinearLayout(this);
    scrollParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollParent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    helpView = new ScrollView(this);
    helpView.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    helpView.setFillViewport(true);

    inside = new LinearLayout(this);
    inside.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    inside.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    helpView.addView(inside);

    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.learn1);
    img.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



    ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.learn2);
    img2.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    inside.addView(img);
    inside.addView(img2);
    scrollParent.addView(helpView);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use ScrollView.LayoutParams instead of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams in line 2

Comment: Tried, Didn't work @HeisenBerg

Comment: try LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT instead of ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

Comment: Still not working @HeisenBerg

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

activity_demo.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/myLinear"
    tools:context="com.example.ricardo.demo.Demo">


</LinearLayout>
```

Demo.java

```
package com.example.ricardo.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;


public class Demo extends Activity {

    private ScrollView helpView = null;
    private LinearLayout inside = null, myLinear = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

        myLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinear);
        showImages();
    }

    private void showImages(){
        helpView = new ScrollView(this);
        helpView.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        helpView.setFillViewport(true);

        inside = new LinearLayout(this);
        inside.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        inside.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        helpView.addView(inside);

        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        img.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        inside.addView(img);

        ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        img2.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        img2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        inside.addView(img2);

        myLinear.addView(helpView);

    }

}
```

Comment: There was no thing named "WRAP_PARENT" so I changed it. And it didn't help at all.

Comment: Sorry, is WRAP_CONTENT, use ctrl + space for help of IDE

Comment: Yeah I did that and changed it to WRAP_CONTENT but didn't help. @Woz

Comment: Add setLayoutParams(match_parent, wrap_content) to img1 and img2

Comment: what is your output now?

Comment: I copied your code and ran it. Result was the same. Then I commented the line "inside.addView(img);" to see what happens. The second Image was shown but it's height was too long (more than screenHeight, I should scroll down to see the bottom). Then I uncommented that line with a change, I moved both addView lines (inside.addView(img & img2) ) at the end. (Before myLinear.addView(helpView)) and both images were shown. But now the problem was that they are so long. They've been stretched. I removed the lines "setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);". @Woz continue on next comment...

Comment: I removed the lines "setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);" Now both images are shown in well size but there is a new problem. assume that the scroll view has Height H. First pic starts after H/3 height and the other starts at 2H/3 height. so there is a lot of empty space. I think it could be solved if I could change the height of scroll view to right height. @Woz

Comment: I explained it in 2 above comments @HeisenBerg

Comment: Post your design final and actual

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. Sorry for my poor English @Woz

Comment: You can upload an image of your design as you expect, and how it looks now. my English is basic too, my language is Spanish .

Comment: OK, This [link](http://sakt.ir/13.PNG) is what I want and this is what it is now [link](http://sakt.ir/14.PNG) . Sizes are not real and I don't have any problem about the size of views. My problem is just their position. @Woz

Answer (score 0):

I think you specify wrong type of layoutParams, you should specify a layoutParam for the viewGroup which the child will be placed in. Try like this:

```
// I don't know which type of layout is the parent of scrollParent, 
// but you should set its layoutParams as well, from your code 
// i assume that is LinearLayout
LinearLayout scrollParent = new LinearLayout(this);
scrollParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
scrollParent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

helpView = new ScrollView(this);
helpView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
helpView.setFillViewport(true);

inside = new LinearLayout(this);
inside.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
inside.setLayoutParams(new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

helpView.addView(inside);

ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.learn1);
img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.learn2);
img2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

inside.addView(img);
inside.addView(img2);
scrollParent.addView(helpView);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited that but result didn't change. Now you mentioned it I have one more question, according to what you said, when a LinearLayout is child and RelativeLayout is parent it should be like this: linear.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.layoutParams(X, Y) ); . What should be X and Y? LinearLayout.layoutParams.MATCH_PARENT or RelativeLayout.layoutParams.MATCH_PARENT? @yahya

Comment: Oopps. Yeah, that too should be parent's :) I forgot to change ScrollView.LayoutParams values, please modify the code as above i editted, and try again.